# Find the variance of $S_N$ in terms of the means and variances of $X$ and $N$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, conditional-expectation, moment-generating-functions

I got this problem from Introduction to Probability by Anderson D, Seppalainen T, Valko B. It is challenge problem 10.55.

Let $X_1,X_2,...$ be i.i.d. random variables and $N$ an independent nonnegative integer valued random variable. Let $S_N=X_1+...+X_N$. Assume that the m.g.f. of $X_i$, denoted $M_X(t)$, and the m.g.f. of $N$, denoted $M_N(t)$ are finite in some interval $(-\delta,\delta)$ around the origin.

1. Express the m.g.f. $M_{S_N}(t)$ of $S_N$ in terms of $M_X(t)$ and $M_N(t)$.
2. Assume $N\sim Poisson(\lambda)$ and $X\sim Ber(p)$, deduce what is the distribution of $S_N$ from part 1.
3. Compute the second moment $\mathbb{E}[S^2_N]$ in terms of the moments of $X$ and $N$ and deduce the variance of $S_N$ in terms of the means and variances of $X$ and $N$.

**My Attempt**

1. We have the formula: If $X_1,...,X_n$ are independent, then
   $$M_{X_1+...+X_n}(t)=M_{X_1}\cdot...\cdot M_{X_n}(t)$$
   So $M_{S_N}=M_{X_1}(t)\cdot...\cdot M_{X_N}(t)$
   but we need it in terms of $M_X{t}$ and $M_{N}(t)$. This is the part I am having trouble on since $N$ is a random variable, not a number.

A hint I was given is that I should decompose the computation of the expectation by conditioning w.r.t. $N$.

So if I try that, I have
$$\mathbb{E}[e^{tS_N}|N=1]=\mathbb{E}[e^{tX_1}]$$
$$\mathbb{E}[e^{tS_N}|N=2]=\mathbb{E}[e^{tX_1}]\mathbb{E}[e^{tX_2}]$$
and so on...
But how would I put this together to find just $\mathbb{E}[e^{tS_N}]$ and make it in terms of $M_X(t)$ and $M_N(t)$?

3. For this part, isn't the second moment equal to the variance? From what I understand about moment generating functions, the first moment is the expectation and the second moment is the variance. Why does it ask for both?

Comment: Try using this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation

Answer (score 1):

So for the first part we can write,
\begin{align}
M_{S_N}(t) = \mathbb{E}[e^{tS_{N}}] &= \mathbb{E}[e^{t\sum_{i=1}^{N}X_i}] \\
&= \mathbb{E}\left[\mathbb{E}[e^{t\sum_{i=1}^{N}X_i}|N]\right], \hspace{5mm} \text{l.i.e} \\
&= \mathbb{E}\left[(\mathbb{E}[e^{tX_1}])^N\right] \\
&= \mathbb{E}\left[e^{\ln(M_X(t))N}\right] \\
&= M_N(\ln(M_X(t))).
\end{align}

For the third part, No the second moment is in general not equal to the variance. Moments are given by $\mathbb{E}[X^k]$ with $k = 1,2,...$ So the variance is equal to the second moment if $\mathbb{E}[X] = 0$.

Now we have that the $k$'th moment of $X$ can be found by taking the $k$'th  derivative of the moment generating function of $X$ and evaluating it at $0$, i.e. $\mathbb{E}[X^k] = M_{X}^{(k)}(0)$. Here $(k)$ denotes the $k$'th derivative.

Comment: Any MGF evaluated at (0) equals $1$. So we just need to find the second derivative, evaluate it at $0$, then subtract one from it to get our variance?

Comment: No, the expected value is the derivative of the mgf evaluated at 0.

Comment: @Stacker When finding the derivative of $M_N(ln(M_X(t)))$, do we need to use the chain rule? So The first derivative is $M_N'(ln(M_X(t)))\cdot \frac{1}{M_X(t)}\cdot M_X'(t)$? Then how would you make this in terms of the mean and variance of $X$ and $N$

Comment: MX(0) is just 1 so we get $E(N)E(X)$ it looks like

Comment: Ohhh. I understand now. So I can repeat the process to find the second derivative and subtract the square of the first derivative from it to find my variance. Thanks